# I'm trying to communicate from RasPi to arduino via Rs485. I'm using an Usb to Rs485 converter on the RasPi side, and Max485 chip on arduino side

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, rs485

I need to connect a RasPi to my existing RS485 network so I can access all of it via internet. I know both devices can send information, but it is not being received by the other

I have a RasPi 4B, with a [USB to Rs485 adapter][1]. This particular adapter has two leds that light up when you are receiving information (RXD) and transmitting information (TXD). They are incredibly useful, and because of them I know that information is being sent out of the RasPi.

The Arduino is an Arduino Mega, and is connected to a [MAX485 Transceiver][2]. I have used these chips extensively in an Arduino to Arduino network, and they function wonderfully.

Wiring has been checked repeatedly:

USB Adapter: A to MAX485 A, B to MAX485 B, GND to Arduino GND

MAX485: VCC to Arduino 5v, GND to Arduino GND, RO to Arduino RX3, DI to Arduino TX3, DE/RE to Arduino pin 3.

In the code below, I am not trying to send information back and forth. I just want to know if I received anything on the Arduino.

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial

rs = serial.Serial(
  port="/dev/ttyUSB0",
  baudrate = 9600,
  parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
  stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
  bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
  timeout=0,
  rtscts = True
  )

if (rs.isOpen() == True):
  rs.close()
rs.open()
rs.reset_input_buffer()

outstr = "5"
rs.write(outstr.encode(encoding = 'ascii'))
```

Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial3.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //Set enable pin as Output
  pinMode(3, LOW);    //Allows MAX485 to recieve
  Serial.println("Engaged.");
  
}

void loop() {

  while(Serial3.available()){
    Serial.println("We got somethin"); //Lets me know if I somehow got something
    if(Serial3.available()){
      byte data = Serial3.read();
      Serial.println(data);
    }
  }

}
```

I have multiples of each MAX485 chip and USB to RS485 adapters, and have tried using them in case something was broken inside the devices. No change.

Thoughts?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNBXZ.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOM8W.jpg

Comment: Probably not the issue but at `rs.reset_input_buffer` You are not calling the function - `rs.reset_input_buffer()`. Also, you might want to ask at [arduino.se].

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I changed it and tried it just in case. My problem persists.

Comment: Serial.write(data) instead of prinln

Comment: That won't affect anything. If the arduino receives any data, it will at least post "We got something" to the serial. Since that never happens, it means Serial3 is never receiving anything